# Auto Fit Column Width for Headers that Allows Space for Filter Drop Down Arrow

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to resize the width of every column on a worksheet to fit the text in the header column AND the drop down arrow that appears when filters are on.

The following code will resize all the columns on the worksheet (as desired) but does it using the standard "auto-fit" function on all rows in the column (not just header row).

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

The code below is closer to what I am looking to accomplish as it sizes the columns based on the header row only.

```
Dim HeaderRow As Range

Set HeaderRow = Application.InputBox("Select the row which contains the headers", "Obtain     Range Object", Type:=1)

HeaderRow.Select

Selection.Columns.AutoFit
```

I am stuck on how to add width to each columns AutoFit width.  I have determined that I would like to add 3.0 to each width to be able to read the header without the drop down filter arrow cutting off the text.

My idea is to add two spaces to each header and then autofit each header column.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this or how to improve the code above to not use selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was in the process of drafting my question I was able to come up with a solution.

The code below allows the user to define which row contains their headers. The macro then adds two spaces to each cell in the user defined 'header row' which contains any value.  These width of these adjusted 'header cells' are then auto-fit.

This seems to work well, but I am curious if anyone else can offer an improvement on the code or perhaps an enhancement to make the macro more useful?

```
Sub Resize_Header_Column()

'==========================================================================
'This macro will resize the column width to fit the text in the header row of a spreadsheet as well as 
'allow space for the drop down filter arrows to not cut off the text of a header
'=========================================================================


ColumnLetter = Split(Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1],     SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Cells.Address(1, 0), "$")(0)

Dim HeaderRow As Long
HeaderRow = Application.InputBox("Insert the row number which contains the headers", "Obtain     Range Object", Type:=1)

Dim HeaderRange As String
HeaderRange = "A" & HeaderRow & ":" & ColumnLetter & HeaderRow

Range(HeaderRange).Select

For Each r In Selection
With r
    .Value = .Text & "  "
End With
Next r

Selection.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread in my search for an answer to the same question you posted.

If your column headers are the largest elements in the column (and therefore the limiting factor of the auto-fit), use

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:H1").AutoFit
```

Note that this assumes that your column headers are in a single row (row 1) from columns A to H. This will force the auto-fit function to use just the column header cells in determining the proper width. Just make sure to apply the AutoFit *after applying your AutoFilter*.